# How to prevent nested promise from hanging?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

The following code works (the user object is written to the console), however the process doesn't exit. I believe one of the promises must not be resolved?

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

Promise.promisifyAll(mongodb);

mongodb.MongoClient.connectAsync("mongodb://localhost/test")
.then(function(db){
    var users = db.collection('users');
    return users.findOneAsync({userName: "someuser"});
})
.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
})
.catch(function(e){
    //handle error
});
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: If you're getting something printed then the promises are definitely resolved.  Is there a reason not to add .finally(function() {process.exit(0);}) to terminate the script when you're done?

Comment: Closing the connection as suggested in answer below causes the code to terminate cleanly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB creates a persistent connection which you're supposed to use for the whole lifecycle of your application.

When you're done with it - close it. That is - call `db.close()`

If you want to write saner code, use `Promise.using` and a `disposer` for making a saner `connectAsync` which does resource management for you.